# Set value from result list of request on writeValue implementation

Tags: angular, observable, angular7, subscribe, controlvalueaccessor

I have an Angular 7 custom component which in `ngOnInit` method has a request to backend like this

```
 ngOnInit() {
    this.elementsRequest$ = this.service.getElements();
    this.elementsRequest$.subscribe((list: any[]) => {
      this.list = list; // list from remote. This is going to be used on writeValue
    });
  }
```

This component implements `ControlValueAccessor` interface. At `writeValue` I have:

```
  writeValue(value: ItemCode[]) {
    if (isNullOrUndefined(this.list)) {
      this.elementsRequest$.subscribe((list: any[]) => {
        this.value = value;
      });
    } else {
      this.value = value;
    }
  }
```

`writeValue` method of custom component must wait to `list` inicialization with the result from `ngOnInit`, due to, the provided value from parents components must be one of the result list.

A parent component is initializing this component with `[undefined, null, "a value"]` values before the result list arrives.

The desired behavior is to keep as value the last passed value from parent (`"a value"`)

The question is:

- How to avoid the three subscriptions to `this.elementsRequest$`?
- In case subcriptions must be necessary, how to ensure that the custom component maintains the last value provided?